# Oracle string content evaluated as identifier

Tags: sql, string, oracle, variables, sqlplus

I defined the next clause in Oracle:

```
DEFINE mytable='users';
```

When I try to get that variable it shows the following error:

```
SELECT &mytable FROM DUAL;

ORA-00904 string: invalid identifier
```

This means that is evaluating 'users' as a variable instead of retrieve the string.

¿How could I fix it?

Comment: If you `set verify on` you can see how the substitution works, and the 'new' statement that it actually tries to run; and hopefully then it will be obvious what's wrong - the `dual` table doesn't have a column called `users`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `quotes` to access this variable `mytable` as in the following:

```
select '&mytable' from dual;

'USERS'
--------------------------------
 users
```